# How to refer to $(this) of plugin instead $(this) of each function? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Developing a little plugin, I found a question that is tearing me up inside. To call my plugin, I use:

```
$('#input').myPlugin();
```

In a given moment, I need use a each inside of my plugin, following is the code:

```
var list = []
var str = 'just a test <b>foo</b> blablabla <b>bar</b>'
str.children('b').each(function(i){  
    // Here I want use the $(this) of each function
    list.append($(this).text())
})
```

After this piece of code I need use another "each" function, but now I don't want use the $(this) of 'each', I want use the "global this". In other words, now I want refer to $('#input'), the element that call my plugin.

```
hashtag.each(function(i)){ 

      // In the first "this" I want refer to $('input'), in the second, to this of each function.
      $(this).functionToFindText($(this))
}
```

How I can tell to jQuery what's the desired this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a variable `var $this = $(this)` before the `.each` loop, and refer to `$this` in the internal callback.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best way to do that, but this works and your answer is the unique, so thanks!

Comment: This is the most common way. It's fine.